# Return nested serializer on update

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get(
            'title', instance.title)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

When I do a get, I see:

```
{
  "title": "some title",
  "tracks": [
    {
      "name": "some track"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use update I get back the updated album, minus the tracks - I'd like to see the tracks in the 201 response. **NOTE**: I don't want the nested items to be writeable, I just want to be able to update the parent and see the existing nested items in the response.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my view. **NOTE:** There will only be one album per user, so some of my view code checks to see if a user exists, and either creates or updates accordingly:

```
class AlbumView(APIView):
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

    def get_object(self, user):
        try:
            return Album.objects.get(user=user)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            return False

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        req = self.get_object(user=request.user)
        if req:
            serializer = AlbumSerializer(req)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response("No album found")

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        req = self.get_object(user=request.user)
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            if req:
                serializer.update(instance=req, validated_data=request.data)
            else:
                serializer.create(user=request.user, validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You can control it by switch `Serializer`, one for update and one for get. Can you post where you use `AlbumSerializer`?

Comment: I've added the code for my view, thanks.

Comment: maybe you only need add `read_only` in nested . Like `tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`. Can you try it?